#  scroller to select numbers

Tags: android, numbers, scroll

I am creating an app where I need the user to input a number. Instead of opening the keyboard I would rather use something likw that timepicker, but do not know how to customize it to fit my needs. I want the user to input a 3 digit number, but changing each number individually. So there should be three selectors from 0 to 9. The + - in the timepicker would work well so if that was customizable that would be good.

Also if there is any chance anyone would know how to do this with a sort of scroll wheel from 0 to 9 rather than the way the timepicker does it that would be awesome. Please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

There is no native control in Android like you need.

But don't worry. I know there is a Picker satisfies your need. It's called Android-wheel. Take a look at its screenshot

[image]

Its author also includes an example of number picker in this app. Let check out and see if it's useful.
http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/

Btw, if you have time, let check out my "Android UI Patterns" app (https://market.android.com/details?id=com.groidify.uipatterns). There will be many Android UI controls helpful for your development.